# PHP, MYSQL and HTML FORMS not working together

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, get

I have this code but when I press the submit button No data is being transferred via Get, with the exemption on the submit.

```
<table cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
    <td>Name</td><td>Today - <?php echo $date;?></td>
    </tr>
    <form method="get" action="update_reg.php">
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE GROUP = 'Penguins' ORDER BY Rank, Name ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
      if($row['Rank'] == "a"){
        $rank = "TOP ";
      }
      if($row['Rank'] == "b"){
        $rank = "MIDDLE ";
      }
      if($row['Rank'] == "c"){
        $rank = "SECOND ";
      }
      if($row['Rank'] == "d"){
        $rank = "BOTTOM ";
      }
      if($row['Rank'] == "e"){
        $rank = "";
      }
      echo $rank . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
      $num = $num + 1;
      echo "<td><input type=\"text\" class=\"today\" id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" data-number=\"" . $num . "\" size=\"1\" maxlength=\"1\"></td></tr>";
      }
    ?>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

For some reason this isn't working, anyone got any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `value=""` attribute and `name=""` attribute to your `<input>`s.

For example:

```
echo "<td><input type=\"text\" class=\"today\" id=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" name=\"" . $row['id'] . "\" data-number=\"" . $num . "\" value=\"" . $num . "\" size=\"1\" maxlength=\"1\"></td></tr>";
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to submit exactly, but place that in the value for the `value` attribute and make sure to give each one a `name` attribute and value.  In my example, I used `$num` for the `value` and `$row['id']` for the `name`.

Answer (score 2):

None of your `<input>` tags have `name` attributes. No `name,` no form submission.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword.
So you need to backtick it as

```
`GROUP`


SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `GROUP` = 'Penguins' ORDER BY Rank, Name
```

UPDATE FROM LAST COMMENT

Input need a name which is not there and if you give same name for all of them they will not work. So give a name="something[]" and on submit get the data as array

Comment: Thanks, that was just an example, normally it is another word, the page is showing fine with data from the DB, but when i fill in the text boxes it produces and click submit no data is transferred.

Comment: what u are trying to submit ? which fields ?

Comment: All <input> boxes which are generated by the PHP echo.

Comment: They need a name which is not there and if you give same name for all of them they will not work. So give a name="something[]" and on submit get the data as array.